# How do I stop Spotify trying to play music files from Dropbox?

Tags: dropbox, spotify

When trying to play a song from dropbox I think I should have hit media player or something. Instead I think I hit spotify always and now it won't let me play my song. It goes right fo spotify and I cant find my song there. How do I change the the player to like internet or media on my galaxy s4

Answer (score 5):

Settings > Application Manager > Spotify > Clear defaults

This will release the filetype from always being executed with Spotify.

The next execution of this filetype will present the dialog for your preference again.

Comment: I actually asked Spotify to remove the action, but nothing as of yet.